# Is there a way to set a null value to decimal datatype in C# without using Nullable<decimal> or 'decimal?'?

Tags: c#-4.0

public decimal Value { get; set; }

I want to set a null value to Value property without using Nullable or '?'

Comment: Can't be done. there is a reason nullables exist ; this is it.

Comment: Even if you implement the getter and the setter, the value returned from getter should be a non-nullable decimal, also the "value" got in the setter will be a of the same type (non-nullable decimal). I think there is no way to do what you want.

Comment: why you want it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with a Value Type. Value Types can't have NULL values. Imagine a value type like being an array of integers.

For example, a Point having two properties X=12 and Y=15  will be conceptually represented in memory like:

[12,15]

If you add let's say a "string" property labeled name "Name" then in the array will be stored the memory address pointing in Heap to that string:

[12,15, 65535] where 65535 represents the heap address.

Taking this in consideration, a Value Type obviously can't be null, in the best case you will have an array full of zero values.

a Nullable is a value type that has actually two properties: the represented T value type and an additional boolean value that says whether conceptually we have a value or not. So we still have a structure but this time we have an additional flag that indicates the "nullability" property.